# Replace values in a dimension of a 2D numpy array, from a map dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, hsv

I need to replace the values of a certain index in all lists inside a list, with a value from a dictionary, which is mapped for a different index of that list.
Or, if the first index value of every list(which are inside a bigger list), equals a key in the dictionary, then the value at the second index in that list, changes to the value from the dict.

```
For ex: L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        D = {'1':50, '4':10, '7':20} ##if first index is any of these keys, then the second index becomes the value
        New List = [[1,50,3],[4,10,6],[7,20,9]]
```

This is because I have a image with HSV values, and need to replace the saturation value of every pixel according to a curve, which describes the saturation for each color(hue), like the Hue vs Saturation curve in after effects.

So a curve describes the saturation values for each hue value, I need to iterate all the pixels, and according to their hue values, change the saturation from a dictionary, hope this explains well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are all natural numbers and the range is not very large, it may be the fastest to make a mapping array and generate the results through the index:

```
>>> L
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> mapping = np.zeros(L[:, 0].max() + 1, int)
>>> mapping[np.fromiter(D, int)] = list(D.values())
>>> mapping
array([ 0, 50,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0, 20])
>>> L[:, 1] = mapping[L[:, 0]]
>>> L
array([[ 1, 50,  3],
       [ 4, 10,  6],
       [ 7, 20,  9]])
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Timing shows this is slightly faster (few %) than my basic loop approach for 1M sub-arrays.  I can't see that there is any fast vectorized approach because of the Dictionary look-up; for example Panda using .replace is somewhat slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for sub in L:
    sub[1] = D.get(str(sub[0]), 0)
```

This uses a default value of 0 if the dictionary does not have the List value.

Produces

```
[[1, 50, 3], [4, 10, 6], [7, 20, 9]]
```

Comment: thanks, it is a bit faster than the other answer here.

Comment: You can of course impose any default value you want such as `None` and check for that if that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done as follows:

```
L = np.array([[1,2,3],[6,4,5],[7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
D = {'1':50, '4':10, '7':20, '8':30, '10':45}
keys = np.array(list(D.keys()), dtype=int)
vals = np.array(list(D.values()), dtype=int)

srt = L.ravel().argsort()

ind = np.searchsorted(L.ravel(),keys, sorter=srt)


r =L.ravel()
r[srt[ind]+1]= vals
print(r.reshape(L.shape))
```

Output:

```
 [[1 50  3]
 [ 6  4 10]
 [ 7 20 30]
 [10 45 12]]
```

Comment: thanks man, shows another way to do the same.

Comment: This is based on numpy and hence is vectorized. Meaning much faster than a python for loop. You can test the speed  on real images.

Comment: Numpy not necessarily faster; but it would be for VERY large arrays. In any case there is a problem with your code: it works as written for the sample data provided where there are 3 elements in L and 3 elements in D but fails if there is a mis-match. Try it with eg. `D = {'1':50, '4':10, '7':20, '8':30}` or with more sub-arrays in L.

Comment: however it doesn't work with: L = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[7,8,9]])

Comment: There is no doubt that the comparison of `O(n^2)` times wastes the performance brought by vectorization.

Comment: Please check now and validate.

Comment: @rummyrummyrum Check the input and output. Its the most generic solution IMHO.

Comment: Works only with data in your answer and not generically. Try with `L = [[1,2,3],[6,4,5],[7,8,9], [7,11,12]]` and see (no) effect on last sub-array. Try with `L = [[1,2,3],[6,4,5],[7,8,9], [10,11,12], [1,2,3], [6,4,5]]` and see (no) effect on last two sub-arrays.

Comment: Even the accepted answer doesn't work on the input. I think OP doesnt want this type of input.